# How can I SELECT field FROM table WHERE id=variable?

Tags: php, variables

I have a variable of the logged in user (`$steamid`) that I need to use to select and echo specific fields from the database. I am using the following code, but it is working incorrectly. All database info is correct, the tables, columns, and variables are not misspelled. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("private","private","private","private");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql = "SELECT `bananas` FROM `es_player` WHERE `steamid` = '$steamID'";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Get field information for all fields
  while ($fieldinfo=mysqli_fetch_field($result))
    {
    printf("bananas: %n",$fieldinfo->bananas);
    }
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

No errors are shown, it simply returns "bananas:" with nothing after it. I feel like I didn't to it correctly, does anyone know what I might've done wrong? Here is a screenshot of my database table so you know what it looks like http://puu.sh/gCY3d/983b738458.png.

Comment: Clarify `it is not working`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Well, it just gives me a blank page. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: I edited the "printf" area because it wasn't filled in properly, but still no luck.

Comment: Where is `$steamID` ? Moon? <> As a sidenote, if the query fails you have nothing that handles it. Since $steamID seems not to be defined the query will (probably) fail, resulting in a blank page <>

Comment: Blank pages indicate disabled error_reporting (where does `$steamID` come from?), and no debugging statements. As for "What am I doing wrong?": obligatory hourly mention of parameter binding, and some pity for chosing mysqli.

Comment: Turn on error reporting if you haven't already and it will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I have the variables and such configured elsewhere, and they are all working fine with my other functions. The variable $steamID works fine, I've already tested it. If you'd like for me to print my entire website somewhere then I can, but I can assure you that the location of the variables isn't the issue. I have $steamID set in the same file as the code I have posted here.

Comment: if $steamID is defined (are you absolutely 100% sure? are you sure that it is scoped properly?), then there may be two possible reasons: 1) The query is returning nothing, therefore the while stops immediatly. 2) The query is failing for some strange reason, you should handle that case using an Else or a Throw.

Comment: 1: How can I enable error reporting for a single document and 2: $steamID is most definitely defined correctly, I am using it in other functions in the same file just fine.

Comment: adding error_reporting(E_ALL); changed nothing, no errors are displayed and my normal page shows. The page is no longer blank, but my script shows nothing.

Comment: It just displays bananas: 0 .... and no errors are being shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = Mysqli_Query($con, "SELECT * FROM `es_player` WHERE `steamid`='$steamID'") or die(mysql_error());

  if( ! mysqli_num_rows($query) ) 
  {
  echo 'No results found.';
  }
  else
  {   
   $bananas_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
   $bananas = $bananas_array['bananas'];
   echo 'Number of bananas: '. $bananas;      
  }
```

If this doesn't work, there is a problem with STEAM_ID format. You could try triming the IDs to be JUST a number, and add the STEAM_x:x: to it later.

Comment: This would be better using bound parameters. We don't know where `$steamID` comes from, but it might be user input.